# Video streaming with object storage bucket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-security, spring-webflux

We are storing the videos in object storage (aws s3/oci os) and using object uri's we are able to play the videos from HTML video player. but if we make the bucket access as private then possible ways are use the pre-authenticated urls or use the object storage sdk api to get the input stream for video object, stream the data using data buffers with `ResourceRegion` in webflux (we can handle all the authentication stuff to access private bucket data).

My query is there any better way to access the private bucket videos (content delivery & streaming)? Can we provide a proxy url instead video object uri directly to client, because I can handle some authentication & authorisation stuff on this url and will hidden the actual video object uri so that we can prevent the video downloading from any third party apps.

Kindly provide suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways. One way is to have a proxy server route external HTTP calls. But that will have only limited features. Another option is to have custom written microservice to stream data from a private/public bucket via an HTTP endpoint with additional custom business logic.

You may refer to this sample Spring Boot microservice code to stream content from OCI Object Storage.

https://github.com/oracle-devrel/oci-sdk-java-samples/tree/main/usecases/storage-file-streaming

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a [new access key and secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html) from your s3 storage, create a small/simple [service/api with node or any language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) of your choice, and every time your app needs a url for a video, it can send a request to the service for a new url which can have an expiration time on it.
Also, in your api you can ensure only your app can access the request for new url.

However, if you mean you want only your browser or your client's to be the only ones that can access the video then that may be difficult. From the above, you can control who can access the url, how long the url is active and who can call the api. Third parties have to do a lot bypass your restrictions

Comment: Thanks for the response. The goal is private video data should not be downloaded by user